# adb remount always requires adb root

Tags: android

I have created a virtual Android Emulator (Nexus_5X_API25) and I need to get the root access. But when I enter adb remount command, it always tells me that the adb is not running as root. I have tried adb root, however, it still has the same question.

What I tried in the command line and the result like this:

```
D:\Android\SDK\platform-tools>adb root

D:\Android\SDK\platform-tools>adb remount

D:\Android\SDK\platform-tools>adb Not running as root. Try "adb root" first.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all**, Emulator is **NOT ALWAYS** be rooted.

If you want to have a rooted Android Emulator, you need to select the image like below (**without Google Play**) when you create the Emulator

> Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image

Don't select below kind of image, i.e. with Google Play

> Google Play Intel x86_64 Atom System Image

Then test your emulator with `adb root` and you should see an message as below:

```
restarting adbd as root
```

or

```
adbd is already running as root
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I built a new emulator and did what you had said, and it worked！

Comment: @leavewang, Glad to help you. Could you please mark my answer as "accepted" if it answers your question? Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry for this late reply to your message. I have accepted your best answer and it really helps me. Thanks !

Comment: @leavewang, no worries, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

If your device is root so you can access to the shell. Try this

Mount as RW:

```
adb shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount,rw /system"
```

Mount as RO:

```
adb shell su -c "mount -o ro,remount,ro /system"
```

Also you could use the [Adbd Insecure app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd), but it's not free.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I have solved the problem using the method provided by @shizhen.